How to access Laravel Octane on default ports with Frankenphp and Docker
I'm struggling with how to set up docker-compose (or dockerfile) to work with Laravel Octane by default.
I'm using basic things from https://frankenphp.dev/docs/docker/.
I also changed Caddyfile to revert_proxy port 8000.
When I'm executing command inside container everything works great, but when I tried supervisor or ENTRYPOINT in Dockerfile it wasn't working. In both cases I know that the octane was running, but it's not working.
I also tried adding ENV FRANKENPHP_CONFIG with frankenphp-worker.php but it didn't change a bit. Booting application just as normal

You will need to provide the ports all these things are running on in your docker compose and inside the docker container to show how you have the host wired up to the vm running the docker container.
